# pascal skips file whilst it is not empty

Tags: pascal

I am trying to read some data from a txt file using pascal.
When I use a while loop to keep doing actions whilst the file has not ended pascal ignores the while loop and proceeds to the end of my program.
Don't really know why this is happening the file I am using is a .txt file which is most certainly not empty!

Code beneath

```
program Wiki_Lezen;

{$mode objfpc}

 TYPE wikiNew=RECORD
  naam,omschrijving:string;
 END;

  var f: file of wikiNew;
  var bestandsNaam:string;
  var wiki:wikiNew;
  var teller:integer;



begin

  writeln('Geef een bestandsnaam op');
  readln(bestandsNaam);
  ASSIGN(f,bestandsNaam);
  RESET(f);

  while not EOF(f) do
  begin
     read(f,wiki);
     writeln('wikinaam: ', wiki.naam);
     writeln('Geef een omschrijving voor wiki');
     readln(wiki.omschrijving);
     write(f,wiki);
  end;

  CLOSE(f);

  writeln;
  writeln('Om het programma te stoppen druk op <ENTER>');
  readln();
end.
```

Comment: You may need to do a 'priming read' - that is, before you enter the `WHILE` loop, attempt to read the first record.

Comment: Did you test that? If I do I find it is a shortstring aka TP string

Comment: Ouch! No @Marco . Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Why are you reading from and writing **to the same file**?

Comment: This is allowed in file of, which are seekable. But the file pointer advances all the time. Suggest to dump filepos(f) after each read(f or wiite(f  to debug

Answer (score 1):

A wikinew record is 512 bytes (two shortstrings with 255 chars + each 1 length byte).

Is your file a series of records of 512 bytes with two shortstrings inside? Or are you trying to read a general textfile?  That won't work. "file of" is for constant size data only.

The file type you are looking for is text, or if that isn't allowed, file of char is needed.

Answer (score 0):

With my code,
which both creates and reads the data file, I cannot reproduce your problem.
The code writes 3 `wiki` records to the file and successfully reads them back.

```
program ReadTextFileTestShortString;

{$mode objfpc}  //{$H+}

uses
  SysUtils;

 type wikiNew = record
  naam,omschrijving:string;
 end;

  var f : file of wikiNew;
  var bestandsNaam:string;
  var wiki:wikiNew;
  var teller:integer;
begin
  // First construct a data file name, based on the executable's name
  bestandsNaam := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + ' Wiki.Dat';

  //  Next, generate the file
  Assign(f, bestandsNaam);
  Rewrite(f);
  for teller := 1 to 3 do begin
    wiki.naam := 'Name' + IntToStr(teller);
    wiki.omschrijving := 'Omschrijving' + IntToStr(teller);
    write(f, wiki);
  end;

  //  Now, read the file
  Reset(f);
  while not Eof(f) do begin
    read(f, wiki);
    writeln('Name: ', wiki.naam);
    writeln('Description: ', wiki.omschrijving);
  end;
  Close(f);
  readln;

end.
```

I will have to leave it to you to investigate why you apparently get different
behaviour with your code.  Perhaps the "user" is not entering a file name which
includes an absolute path and so is reading a different version of the file than
the one you assume.

Comment: Pure objfpc mode is shortstring. only {$mode objfpc} {$h+} is ansistring.

Comment: My guess is that he tries to read a normal textfile this way. That won't work. "file of" is for constant size data only. text, or if that isn't allowed, file of char is needed.