# Lazarus readln doesn't read the variable

Tags: pascal, lazarus

I would like to ask for some help as i'm not able to identify what i did wrong in the following code as in the procedure , it doesn't read the first unit of the record ,  but after that it reads the uj.nev too. It only misses it for the first time which is what i can't understand ,and not only on the school computer but mine too. I would appreciate it if you could explain to me what i did wrong. Thanks in  advance! (the program supposed to read records nev , varos , fizetes , and sort them into ascending order, and then write it out into a text file)

```
program adatbazis;
uses crt,Sysutils;

const
  C_FNAME = 'adatbazis.txt';
var
  a,n,j,l:integer;
  tfout: Textfile;

type
  Tember=record
    nev:string;
    varos:string;
    fizetes:longint;
  end;

procedure beiras(var uj:Tember);
begin
  writeln('nev',j,':');
  readln(uj.nev);
  writeln('varos',j,':');
  readln(uj.varos);
  writeln('fizetes',j,':');
  readln(uj.fizetes);
end;

var
  i,k:integer;
  seged:Tember;
  tomb: array[1..20] of Tember;
begin
  write('n :');
  read(n);
  for j:= 1 to n do begin
    beiras(tomb[j]);
  end;
  writeln('Mi szerint legyen rendezve?');
  repeat
    writeln(' Nev:1 , Fizetes:2 , varos:3');
    readln(l);
  until l<> 1 or 2 or 3;
  if l=1 then  begin
    For j:= 1 to n-1 do begin
      for k:= 2 to n do begin
        if tomb[j].nev>tomb[k].nev then
        begin
          seged:=tomb[j];
          tomb[j]:=tomb[k];
          tomb[k]:=seged;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  if l=2 then begin
    For j:= 1 to n-1 do begin
      for k:= 2 to n do begin
        if tomb[j].fizetes>tomb[k].fizetes then
        begin
          seged:=tomb[j];
          tomb[j]:=tomb[k];
          tomb[k]:=seged;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  if l=3 then  begin
    For j:= 1 to n-1 do begin
      for k:= 2 to n do begin
        if tomb[j].varos>tomb[k].varos then
        begin
          seged:=tomb[j];
          tomb[j]:=tomb[k];
          tomb[k]:=seged;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  AssignFile(tfout, C_FNAME);
  rewrite(tfout);
  for i:=1 to n do begin
    writeln(tfout,tomb[i].nev,'  ',tomb[i].varos,'  ',tomb[i].fizetes);
  end;
  CloseFile(tfout);
  clrscr;
  writeln('done');
  readln;
end.
```

Comment: The working example in my answer to this q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48097196/pascal-skips-file-whilst-it-is-not-empty may help you see where you are going wrong.  Briefly, you need to be very careful - and understand what you are doing - if you try to store records which contain `string` fields in a file.

Comment: Besides bad formatting, which makes it hard to read, you have several issues here at a glance. For instance, what do you think, `repeat ... until l <> 1 or 2 or 3;` really does?

Comment: Why did you ask this question before debugging your program? That's not good enough.

Comment: FWIW, `1 or 2 or 3 = 3`. Take a look at Delphi's operator precedence in the online help.

Comment: I believe the problem (why you are asking your question) lies in the difference between `Read()` and `ReadLn()`. Read carefully the documentation to learn that difference, then verify that you use these functions correctly.

Comment: @TomBrunberg that sounded good but i changed readln to read and now when i run it  i give n and after that it writes the 3 writeln that are in the procedure , and reads only the last one. I deleted the parts that the others said but the problem still remains

Comment: I told you to **read carefully to learn the difference**, and then to verify that you are using them correctly, didn't I? Irrational trying until not failing anymore is not programming.

Comment: Please stop this futile attempt to program. Debug your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the essential difference between the `FPC` `Read()` and `ReadLn` functions when used with `standard input` is not very well documented (in the Delphi documentation it can be read). Therefore, the answer to your question is the following.

According to the `FPC` documentation, `CRLF`, `CR` and `LF`, all are recognized as `End-Of-Line (EOL)` characters, so in the following `EOL` stands for any of those.

**When calling `Read(s)`** where `s: string;` the program waits for user input until an `EOL` is added to the input buffer. The input characters up until (but excluding) the `EOL` are removed from the buffer and passed to `s`. **The `EOL` is left in the input buffer**.

Next call to `Read(s)` will immediately recognize the `EOL` in the input buffer, and will not wait for user input. The `EOL` continues to remain in the buffer, and therefore no subsequent `Read(s)` will wait for user input.

*The first call to `ReadLn(s)` after a `Read(s)` will also immediately detect the `EOL` in the buffer and not wait for user input.*

**When calling `ReadLn(s)`** the program waits (as in previous example) for user input until an `EOL` is added to the input buffer. The input characters up until (but excluding) the `EOL` are removed from the buffer and passed to `s`. **Then the `EOL` is removed from the buffer and thrown away**.

Next call to `ReadLn(s)` will again stop and wait for user input.

In your code you are calling `Read(n)` in the very beginning of the execution. Then, in `beiras()` you are calling `ReadLn()` which detects the `EOL` in the buffer and therefore returns immediately, but also removes the `EOL` from the buffer. Subsequent calls to `ReadLn()` will now wait for user input.

**The cure** is iow to change the `Read()n` to a `ReadLn(n)` in the beginning of your program.