# Read() not working for string type inputs in an array

Tags: arrays, input, pascal, freepascal

I'm new to pascal and I have been working on a project recently. And here's a sample of it to where I got the problem. I'm trying to assign **string type input** values to **string type array** but it wont work. Basically, it wont allow me to enter data. It skips read(). **Cannot enter data**.But it *works when* I change the data type in both of them to *Integer*.

```
program temp;
var input_array : array[0..5] of string;
    k : integer;
    y : string;

begin
    for k := 0 to 5 do   
        begin
            writeln('Enter character : ');
            read(y);                    // Not working
            input_array[k] := y;
        end;
    for k := 0 to 5 do             
        writeln(input_array[k]);
end.
```

Comment: Does `ReadLn` work?

Comment: No it wont work

Comment: Do you know you need to press Enter to make `Readln` return? Do you want the user to enter a string or only a single character?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this Q&A:https://stackoverflow.com/a/66975300/2663863

Comment: yeah.. but it still dont give me any sign of `read`. so i cant press enter, it directly shows me the end of the program @AndreasRejbrand

Answer (score 0):

The FPC is not a fully ISO-compliant compiler, yet it’s worth taking a look at the standards anyway. In ISO 10206 “Extended Pascal” you will find the following note:

> e) If `v` is a *variable‑access* possessing a *fixed‑string‑type* of capacity `c`, `read(f, v)` shall satisfy the following requirements. [… super technical mumbo jumbo …]
>
> NOTE — 6 If `eoln(f)` is initially `true`, then no characters are read, and the value of each component of `v` is a space.

Bottom line, you can “fix” your `program` by inserting the following conditional `readLn` which will “consume” any “remnant” *end‑of‑line* character prior your actual `read`:

```
    for k := low(input_array) to high(input_array) do
    begin
        write('Enter character: ');
        
        if EOLn then
        begin
            readLn;
        end;
        
        read(input_array[k]);
    end;
```